# How to use the result of another query?

Tags: neo4j

I was making some requests on Neo4j, and I've a little trouble at making one in particular.

These are the nodes and relationships I have on my database
[image]

Two of the elements:

[image]

[image]

I want to return the persons who are driving ("conduire") the same "Voiture" as Alice.
This is what I wrote:

```html
MATCH ((a:Personne)-[p:Conduire]->(b:Vehicule))
WHERE  b.`Type`='Voiture' AND id(b) in [MATCH ((a:Personne)-[p:Conduire]->(b:Vehicule))
WHERE  a.Nom='Alice' 
RETURN id(b)]
RETURN a.Nom
```

Comment: What is the problem on your query? Can you highlight what is the incorrect output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query to return the persons who are driving the same car as Alice. Note that this will not return Alice because the match on b will not repeat the match made on a.

```
MATCH (a:Personne)-[:Conduire]->(:Vehicule)<-[:Conduire]-(b:Personne)
WHERE  a.Nom='Alice' 
RETURN b.Nom
```